# xml file content replacement form variable value

Tags: xml, shell, xml-parsing

it seems its very complex to insert xml content variable from shell script to a specific portion of xml based on the condition which satisfying

I have followed many threads in internet and couldn't find any solution to fulfill my requirement here.

```
HEADER=$(cat <<EOF
<policies>
EOF)

FOOTER==$(cat <<EOF
</policies>
EOF)
IN_IP_FILTER=$(cat <<EOF
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <ip-filter action="allow">
            <address-range from="$ipAddressesFrom" to="$ipAddressesTo" />
        </ip-filter>
    </inbound>
EOF)

################Variables##################
source parse_yaml.sh
eval $(parse_yaml sample2.yaml policy)

echo ".............Eval Result..............................."
for f in $policy_ ; do eval echo \$f \$${f}_ ; done
echo "............Eval Result................................"
echo " ********policy is ************ "
echo "{$IP_FILTER}"

for f in $policy_ ; do
  if [[ $(eval echo \$${f}_name) == "ipfilter" ]]; then
    echo " given policy name is ipfilter "
    for g in $(eval echo \$${f}_session_); do
      if [[ $(eval echo \$${g}) == "inbound" ]]; then
      echo "add the add above Ipfilter string to the inbound session of xml"
      echo "${HEADER}" >> result_$(eval echo \$${f}_name).xml
      echo "${IN_IP_FILTER}" >> result_$(eval echo \$${f}_name).xml
      fi
      if [[ $(eval echo \$${g}) == "outbound" ]]; then
      echo "add the add above Ipfilter string to the outbound session of xml"
      fi
      if [[ $(eval echo \$${g}) == "backend" ]]; then
      echo "add the add above Ipfilter string to the backend session of xml"
      fi
    done
```

The file which need to customized based on the condition is as below , but need to replace only the content which is satisfying from the condition.

initial_policy file

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
         $(ip_filter)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)
         $(rate-limit-by_subkey)
         $(rate-limit-by_DevID)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)+$(rate-limit-by_DevID)
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
         $(ip_filter)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)
         $(rate-limit-by_subkey)
         $(rate-limit-by_DevID)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)+$(rate-limit-by_DevID)
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
         $(ip_filter)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)
         $(rate-limit-by_subkey)
         $(rate-limit-by_DevID)
         $(rate-limit-by_ip)+$(rate-limit-by_DevID)
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
         $(rate-limit-by-ip_error)
         $(rate-limit-by_DevID_error) 
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: Could you please described what exactly you're trying to do? What does the input XML look like, what is the condition you're looking for, and what is your desired output?

Comment: Here I am looking for a way to create a custompolicy file by replacing the specic content in the initial_policy.xml file by going through the shell script condition.
For example, if the "policy_session" in the script satisfies as "inbound", the variable of that policy should be applied to the "inbound" session and similarly for each session of the policy file.

Comment: Did u try option with xmlstarlet?

Comment: Yes.. But couldn't find a proper way out of it